# Avoiding piecewise definition for doubling and tripling alternatively

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations

My data doubles, then triples, then doubles, then triples. 
I can't figure out how to write a function $f(N)$ for the data without using a piecewise function. Is it possible?

Here is an example if the first datum was $1$:

$$f(1)=1\qquad
f(2)=2\qquad
f(3)=6\qquad
f(4)=12\qquad
f(5)=36\qquad
f(6)=72$$

Comment: Also, I'd like to know if there's a way to start a new line without creating such a big space, and without using bullets. As you can see, the 6 function evaluations in my question do not need to take up so much vertical space!

Comment: See Edit for one easy formatting option.

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you want to have $f(2n+1)=c\cdot 2^n\cdot 3^n$ and $f(2n+2)=c\cdot 2^{n+1}\cdot 3^n$ where $c=f(1)$ without dividing into cases like this? Perhaps
$$
f(N)=c\cdot 2^{\frac12\left(N-0.5+0.5\cdot(-1)^N\right)}\cdot 3^{\frac12\left(N-1.5-0.5\cdot(-1)^N\right)}
$$
Here is a [table made with Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table+%28%28N-0.5%2B0.5*%28-1%29%5EN%29%2F2%2C%28N-1.5-0.5*%28-1%29%5EN%29%2F2%29+for+N+from+1+through+15) showing how these exponents behave. And here is [another table](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%202%5E%281%2F2*%28N-0.5%2B0.5*%28-1%29%5EN%29%29*3%5E%281%2F2*%28N-1.5-0.5*%28-1%29%5EN%29%29%20for%20N%20from%201%20to%2010) showing values of $f$ for $c=1$ corresponding to your example.

Comment: Surely this can be simplified using floor and ceiling rather than expressions using $(-1)^n$...

Comment: @ErickWong: Indeed, you must be thinking of something like $$f(N)=c\cdot2^{\lceil N/2\rceil}\cdot3^{\lfloor (N-1)/2\rfloor}$$ which is indeed shorter to read. I suppose to some degree this is a matter of taste.